# How can I connect Coveralls and Circle CI in GitHub?

Tags: continuous-integration, code-coverage, circleci, coveralls

I need a little (maybe a lot more than a little) direction in combining these two services to work together. I have added the `COVERALLS_REPO_TOKEN` enviornment variable in the CircleCI settings online. I also have a `.coveralls.yml` file that has the following:

```
service_name: circleci
repo_token: the automated generated token
```

The CircleCI documentation [does point this out](https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/code-coverage/#coveralls), but I this leaves me confused. The repo is enabled on Coveralls, but from then on it is not very clear.

Anyone know of a solution?

I have [cross-posted this question](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/failing-test-circleci/24929) to the CircleCI Discourse forum.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the issue? If so, can you please share your findings

Answer (score 0):

For a java, gradle project that generates code coverage reports using `jacoco`, along with adding `COVERALLS_REPO_TOKEN` environment variable, I had to use the [gradle coveralls plugin](https://github.com/kt3k/coveralls-gradle-plugin)

In CircleCI, I see the below logs after using the gradle plugin:

```
> Task :coveralls
service name: circleci
service job id: null
repo token: present (not shown for security)
[message:Job #39.1, url:https://coveralls.io/jobs/XXXjobId]
```

I didn't have to add the `.coveralls.yml` file

Comment: Does it generate code coverage that I link to GitHub as a badge?

Comment: Yes, the link to the badge was `https://coveralls.io/repos/github/:org/:repo/badge.svg?branch=master`